# How to make custom class bindable in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a class,

```
internal class PageInformation : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty NameProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PageInformation));

    public static DependencyProperty PageUriProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("PageUri", typeof(string), typeof(PageInformation));

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Uri PageUri
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

How can I bind it to some data source?

My idea is to have an XML file which stores the information about all the pages in the application, have this class in `<Page.Resources>` and bind it to the XML file.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<Elements>
      <Element Name="Administration" DisplayName="Administration" Value="1" PageUri="Administration.xaml" >
            <Element Name="Categories" DisplayName="Categories" Value="2" PageUri="Administration.xaml" ></Element>
            <Element Name="Goals" DisplayName="Goals" Value="3" PageUri="Administration.xaml" ></Element>
            <Element Name="Settings" DisplayName="Settings" Value="4" PageUri="Administration.xaml" ></Element>
      </Element>
</Elements>
```

I want to have have the XAML like this:

```
    <Page.Resources>
            <local:PageInformation 
                x:Key="pageInfo" 
                Name="{Binding XPath=/Elements/Element[@Name='Administration']}" 
                Source="/samples.xml" >
            </local:PageInformation>
    </Page.Resources>
```

When I have value for `Name` property, I want to write code to populate other properties as well (probably by using the data context?).

Can somebody tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To run code when the Name property changes, specify a PropertyChangedCallback in the dependency property registration:

```
public static DependencyProperty NameProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PageInformation),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnNameChanged));

private static void OnNameChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // do whatever you want here
}
```

Your OnNameChanged handler can then populate other properties of the PageInformation.

Note that if you are wanting *other* WPF elements to update in response to the Name change, you would do that by binding their properties to the PageInformation's Name property.